# Verifying session still valid with IdentityModel/IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, identitymodel

I can't get IdentityModel to validate if the token still has a valid session. Here's my client code. `_http` is an instance of `HttpClient`.

Don't judge me on using username/password in this instance. It's with a trusted application and I'm starting off with the easier scenario first with plans to move on to the hybrid model next.

```
var discovery ??= await _http.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("http://localhost:5000");
var response = await _http.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
            {
                Address = discovery.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                Scope = "api1",
                UserName = "test",
                Password = "test"
            }); // This succeeds while returning an AccessToken
var introspectionResponse = await _http.IntrospectTokenAsync(new TokenIntrospectionRequest
            {
                Address = discovery.IntrospectionEndpoint,
                ClientId = ClientId,
                ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
                Token = response.AccessToken
            }); // This fails with an unauthenticated error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess here is that it must be a reference token flow. It is a bit confusing. And the confusion here is `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`.

1. The `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` that you have supplied while creating the `AccessToken` are end-user's `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`.
2. The `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` that you have supplied while introspecting the `AccessToken` should be your resource's `Name` and It's `Secret`, *not the end-users `ClientId` and `ClientSecret`*.

In `IdentityServer`, The Client of an introspection endpoint is an API or Resource, not the end-user. Read the full docs [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html).

In your case, Pass the `api1` as `ClientId` and Secret of `api1` as `ClientSecret` while introspecting the `AccessToken`. It should work.

Comment: Thank you! This gets me a lot closer. Now the token checks out, but the `IsActive` property is always false.

Comment: I got it. I needed to add the scope to the API Resource serverside. Still trying to get the hang of the terminology here.